# Write a program that converts unary input to binary, decimal, and hexadecimal equivalents

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

Write a program that accepts input (through stdin) as a string of unary numbers delimited by spaces, and prints the equivalent string of numbers in binary, decimal, and hexadecimal. These unary symbols are allowed:

- stroke, `'/'` or `'\'`
- Decimal `1`
- ASCII `'I'`
- ASCII `'-'`

Your program does *not* have to support all symbols, but it must use at least one. Zero should be represented as simply two spaces (the lack of unary symbols)

e.g. if the input is

**Test Cases:**

Input:

```
1 11 111 1111111111
```

Example Output:

```
1 2 3 10

1 2 3 A

1 10 11 1010
```

Output must be to standard output. If no standard output is available, use whatever output logging stream is available.

It does not have to print the converted strings in any particular order; it must print the binary, hexadecimal, and decimal string equivalents, but it does not have to print in that specific order.

This is code-golf, so shortest program wins!

Comment: Hi Mason, welcome to PPCG. Your challenge looks good over all. A few questions: Is the number 0 in unary an allowable input? Do solutions need to accept all of the specified symbols as inputs, or the one of their choice? How flexible is the output format? Can output bases be in any order? Do they need to space + newline separated?

Comment: @isaacg 0 in unary is simply the lack of any unary symbols; a null value. The representation for zero (for this program) should be an extra space. Symbols are of the programmer's choice. Output format is simply print the string of numbers in one base, then  another, then the last. Only spaces are delimeters.

Comment: Can it be a function instead of a full program?

Comment: Does it have to accept input through STDIN?

Comment: Please specify all rules in the challenge, comments are not guarenteed to stick around forever and are therefore not a suitable place to do that. Also you should add some testcases, especially for the edge cases.

Comment: Hey Mason, I'm voting to close this challenge as "Unclear what you're asking" until you add some more details, and some test cases. Right now, it's not really sure what we're supposed to do with extra spaces and what kind of inputs we will have to handle. If you make that clear, I will happily retract my close vote.

Comment: Also, don't accept an answer until maybe a week after posting.  It will just change too much as people post more answers.

Comment: I've edited an obvious error in the example output, but why is the symbol `0`  being used in the input?  It's not listed as one of the "allowable" symbols. I would **either** be prescriptive and allow one particular symbol (plus space) in the input, **or** allow us to use absolutely any symbol (within the printable ASCII set.)

Comment: Also, is it necessary to print all the outputs of one base before the others? Or can all three outputs for each number be given before moving onto the next? To put it another way, is the following acceptable? `1 1 1 2 2 10 3 3 11 10 A 1010`

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, 68 bytes

```
i=input().split(" ")
for f in[bin,str,hex]:print(*map(f,map(len,i)))
```

Outputs like such:

```
0b1 0b10 0b11
1 2 3
0x1 0x2 0x3
```

If the `0b` and `0x` are not allowed then that can be solved at the cost of 17 extra bytes by changing the second line to:

```
for f in[bin,str,hex]:print(*(f(len(n))[2*(f!=str):]for n in i))
```

Or using this version (minified version of My Ham DJ's answer):

```
i=input().split(" ")
for b in"dxb":print(*("{:{}}".format(len(x),b)for x in i))
```

Comment: This is invalid, because it drops 0 in unary (2 consecutive spaces)

Comment: @isaacg Should be solved now.

Comment: @orlp In `111<space><space>11`, your code counts the last number ("11") as a literal 11 in decimal. It should instead be 2 (since its length is 2). I recommend using regex for this (if you can).

Comment: @R.Kap No it doesn't? I have no clue what you're talking about. Make sure you're running in Python 3, not Python 2.

Comment: @orlp Well, running `"111<2 spaces>11"` in Python 3.5.1 returns the output `(4 0 3)
(4 0 3)
(100 0 11)`

Comment: @R.Kap My program doesn't use quotes around the input, you entered input with quotes. `"111` is 4 characters, `11"` is 3.

Comment: @orlp Yeah, you were right. I did it without quotes, and it works like it should. You should clarify that in your post.

Comment: @R.Kap No I shouldn't. I use the exact same input format as described in the question - no further clarification needed.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 76 bytes

```
s=>[2,10,16].map(b=>s.split` `.map(n=>n.length.toString(b)).join` `).join`
`
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
mjLld[2T16)c
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mjLld%5B2T16%29c&input=%221%2011%20111%22&debug=0)

Output is a list of lists with each sublist containing the binary, decimal and hex representation of the corrosponding input number as a list of digits.

Comment: This is invalid, because it drops 0 in unary (2 consecutive spaces)

Comment: @isaacg As far as the original post is concerned this is valid. Right now it's hard to tell without digging through the comments. I think we should instead focus on making the post better, and then I'll fix or delete my answer once the spec is clear.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5, 61 bytes:

<strike>(*+17 since zeroes count as an extra space*)</strike>

```
lambda g:[(bin(len(f)),hex(len(f)),len(f))for f in g.split(" ")]
```

Pretty much speaks for itself. It is a lambda function, so you must provide input. Then, the function takes "g", which is your input, and outputs the correct values. If, for instance, the input is `"111 11"`, output is as follows:

> [('0b11', '0x3', 3), ('0b10', '0x2', 2)]

I honestly think that including the `0b` and `0x` is a better choice than removing them, since then this way, you can differentiate between those numbers that are hexadecimal, those which are binary, and those which are just plain denary (decimal).

<strike>And now, if the input is, for instance, `"011"`, it counts the `0` as an extra space, and as a result outputs `[('0b10', '0x2', 2)]`.</strike>

**EDIT:** AS per @isaacg's input, I have now fixed by program, and it should work as it should. The code now has the ability for extra spaces between ones to become zeroes. Now, if the input is, for instance, `11<space><space>1`, the output is `[('0b1', '0x1', 1), ('0b0', '0x0', '0'), ('0b10', '0x2', 2)]` counting the extra space as a `'0 '`.

Comment: This is invalid, because it drops 0 in unary (2 consecutive spaces)

Comment: @isaacg I did not realize that 0 counts as an extra space. That's fixed now.

Comment: I was talking about the other way around - `1<space><space>11` should become `1 0 2` in decimal

Comment: @isaacg How is that? Are you saying each extra space between characters counts as a zero?

Comment: @isaacg Okay, I get it now. Edit now in progress...

Comment: @isaacg What do you think now?

Comment: Looks like it works to me.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 14 bytes

```
dcmlD
mb2Rmb16
```

[Try it here](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=dcmlD%0Amb2Rmb16&input=1++11+1111111111111111)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>89</s> 58 bytes

Anonymous function; Returns a list of lists where each sublist contains binary, decimal, and hex representations, and accounts for extra spaces.

@manatwork is a Ruby wizard

```
->s{[2,10,16].map{|b|s.split(/ /).map{|n|n.size.to_s(b)}}}
```

Without the need to check for the spare spaces meaning 0, it drops to 53 bytes:

```
->s{[2,10,16].map{|b|s.split.map{|n|n.size.to_s(b)}}}
```

Comment: Why not go with your second code changing `.split` → `.split(/ /)`? Would handle 0 and would still be shorter than your first code.

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 136 bytes

```java
s->{String[]l=s.split(" ",-1);s="";for(int i=2;i<17;i+=i<3?8:6){for(String n:l)s+=Integer.toString(n.length(),i)+" ";s+="\n";}return s;}
```

[Try it online!](http://ideone.com/z5hH0L)

This is an anonymous function (lambda) that takes a String and returns a String representing the output as described.

Full explanation will come later today.

Comment: Full program with STDIN coming